# How to remove word from dataframe nad plot

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, replace

I created some plot with 20 popular words from tweet.
[image]

But im not sure what is the best method to remove special character like ' between trump and business and says vote . I had tokenized my tweets.
Append or replace ?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do without knowing your code. But you can apply something like the following to the array or list that holds the most common words:

```
 words = [word for word in words if word != "'" and word != '"']
```

But really you should tokenize your tweets differently! You are likely tokenizing

```
Trump isn't Biden
```

as

```
["Trump", "isn", "'", "t", "Biden"]
```

which is where the `'` and `"` likely come from. You should change it to

```
["Trump", "isn't", "Biden"]
```

Comment: I trying create for like this : def cleaning(text):
    text = [word for word in words if word != "'" and word != '"']
    return text

df['Tweet_tokenized'] = df['Tweet_tokenized'].apply(lambda x: cleaning(x)) but isn't work before i used Hero library to stopwords and cleaning tweets

Comment: Try using `df = df[~df['Tweet_tokenized'].isin(['"', "'"])]`

Comment: It's crashing my plot ... :( IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: What is the error message? I'm saying to use the line instead of the `apply` and the `cleaning` function.

Comment: i used instead apply, but isnt work and my plot totally crash

Comment: I need more details on what is wrong to help you further